# NSPopUpButton text overlaps menu image

Tags: cocoa

I am using the following to create an NSPopupButton programmatically:

```
...
    NSPopUpButton *accessoryView = [[NSPopUpButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 24) pullsDown:YES];

    NSFont *aFont = [NSFont systemFontOfSize:[NSFont systemFontSizeForControlSize:NSSmallControlSize]];

    [accessoryView setBezelStyle:NSRecessedBezelStyle];
    [accessoryView setFont:aFont];
    [accessoryView setShowsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside:YES];
    [accessoryView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewMinYMargin];

    NSArray *popupItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Your Account", @"Sign In", @"Create Account", nil];

    [accessoryView addItemsWithTitles:popupItems];
...
```

Now, when I add the NSPopUpButton to my view, I end up with the button's text overlapping the icon used for the dropdown menu.  I have seen this previously when I use NSControl:setAlignment but I am not using this here.  Here is the output:

[image: NSPopUpButton overlaps menu icon]

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Take care,

Jeremy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just so happens this is a simple fix.  (Thanks Beelsebob on irc.freenode.net!)  Basically, you need to have the following code:

```
[[accessoryView cell] setArrowPosition:NSPopUpArrowAtBottom];
```

in there somewhere.  (I added it just below the line to add the menu items.)  I had read the API docs on this call a few times before, since I had implemented the same call with a value of NSPopUpNoArrow to remove the arrow as an interim fix, but it didn't make it clear that the proper value being used above would do what it's doing.  Problem solved.